# calling window.innerHeight upon window resize event doesn't give correct height

Tags: javascript, iphone, firefox

I am using window.onresize to listen for viewport size changes so I can scale my content appropriately (It's a game UI, so it seems easiest to use window.onresize + css scale, other suggestions are welcome).

However, on certain browsers, calling window.innerHeight or window.innerWidth right after the onresize is fired gives the wrong result.

Here is a minimal working example:

```
<html>
  <head>
    <title>Firefox Resize bug</title>
    <link
      rel="manifest"
      href='data:application/manifest+json,{ "name": "onresize bug", "display":"standalone"}'
    />
  </head>
  <body>
    Height: <span id="heightField"></span>
    <br />
    Width: <span id="widthField"></span>
    <script>
      const heightField = document.getElementById("heightField");
      const widthField = document.getElementById("widthField");
      const updateSize = () => {
        heightField.textContent = window.innerHeight;
        widthField.textContent = window.innerWidth;
      };
      window.onresize = updateSize;
      updateSize();
    </script>
  </body>
</html>
```

This works fine in iOS 12 Safari, when you change the orientation, the height and width update correctly.

However, it does not work on iOS Firefox/Chrome (at least, not reliably), and it does not work if you add this app to the home screen on an iPhone (see the manifest in the example above)

I've been getting around this by firing my updateSize 500ms after a onresize event, but what's really going on here?

Comment: Still a problem on iPad IOS 14.4.1 as of Mar 18 2021

Comment: Same in iOS 15 as of Sep 1 2022

Answer (score 4, accepted):

It's a bug in webkit.

https://bugs.webkit.org/show_bug.cgi?id=185886

> In iOS, the `window.onresize` event fires in a WKWebView when the device switches orientation. However, if the WKWebView is positioned WITH Auto Layout, `window.innerWidth` and `window.innerHeight` will report incorrect values from within the `window.onresize` event handler. But, if the WKWebView is positioned manually WITHOUT using Auto Layout, `window.innerWidth` and `window.innerHeight` will report correct values in the event handler.

Comment: The same problem is present in Chrome (Macbook Pro) as of right now.

Answer (score 1):

initial-scale and shrink-to-fit can be a solution for your problem.
[Using the viewport meta tag to control layout on mobile browsers](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Mozilla/Mobile/Viewport_meta_tag)

Add viewport meta to your head

```
<meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1, shrink-to-fit=no">
```

Comment: Thanks for the suggestion, this seems useful. I'm not sure if it will work for my current project though, since I am not scaling the whole document to fit. I am only scaling certain components.